# Dealing with Optional ListBox values in Spring MVC

Tags: java, forms, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC application. My JSP allows the user to select a value from a drop down list - this is optional - they do hot *HAVE* to make a selection.

On my JSP I have code similar to

```
    <form:select path="referral.gpsurgery.id" >
     <form:option value="-1" label="--- Select ---"/>
     <form:options items="${gpsurgery}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="practiseName"/>
</form:select>
```

If the user does not make a selection, a referral.gpsurgery object is passed thru to my controller method with an id value of "-1" ( which is what I would expect ). What this actually means as far as my code is concerned is that when the data is persisted, the gpsurgery field on my referral entity should be set to null.

It feels like Spring should sort this out for me, rather than me having to look at my object graph and remove any gpsurgery instances which have an id of "-1", but I am drawing a blank on how to achieve this. It seems like such a common use case that there must be a standard way of doing it.

Comment: I think your assumption is not correct. It's an [issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7053) in Spring MVC project.

Comment: Duplicated by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162497/spring-mvc-form-tags-is-there-a-standard-way-to-add-no-selection-item

Comment: Thanks Behrooz - the duplicated question gave me just what I needed. Change you comments to an answer and I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As also stated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162497/spring-mvc-form-tags-is-there-a-standard-way-to-add-no-selection-item), you can use:

```
<form:select path="referral.gpsurgery.id">
  <form:option value="">&nbsp;</form:option>
  <form:options items="${gpsurgery}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="practiseName"/>
</form:select>
```