# How to add an unselected item to a field:select in Spring MVC?

Tags: forms, spring-mvc, select, field

I'm trying of add a "field:select to a form without an item selected in my .jspx file, using Spring MVC, but I can't get it. I need to add a first item empty or with a phrase like "--- Select an option ---", and that, with this empty item selected,  the property required of Spring MVC at "true" find unselected the field.

My code is this:

```
<field:select field="cluster" id="c_curve_cluster" itemValue="clave" itemLabel="valor" items="${cluster}" path="cluster" z=""/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring MVC Form tags: Is there a standard way to add "No selection" item?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162497/spring-mvc-form-tags-is-there-a-standard-way-to-add-no-selection-item)

Answer (score 2):

```
<form:select path="color" title="color" >
     <form:option value="">--- Select an option ---</form:option>
     <form:options items="${colorList}" />
</form:select>
```